# Does local and live postgresql database name and user have to match?

Tags: postgresql

I have a local dev database I have been filling up with data. It uses a different database name, user, and password than my live database.

I went to my live server and made a backup. I also then ran the following command to create a sql file.

```
pg_dump -U myuser -h localhost mydb > db.sql
```

My question is, do I need to recreate my live database using the same name and user name as my local dev branch?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another database name when restoring the database and you can restore the database with another user provided that the user has superuser privilege.

With your pg_dump command you just need to create the database before running restore.

For example (assuming `su1` is a superuser):

```
create database mydb1 owner su1;
```

To restore your pg_dump backup you just need to run:

```
psql -U su1 -d mydb1 < db.sql
```

Comment: When I do this. I get a lot of "ERROR: role "jsonparser_user" does not exist" Is this fine?

Comment: That's because `pg_dump` does not export user, roles. For this you need to use `pg_dumpall`.